# Convert java library to Android Library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a standard way to convert a java library in Android Studio to an android library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps :

1. In build.gradle replace the plugin line as `apply plugin: 'java-library'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` and add the following :

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27

         defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

             testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

         }

         buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

     }
```

2. Add Android manifest file
3. Add resources files if needed

Open in Android Studio and the module should load as an Android Library.

Comment: Important to mention: after changing the files, perform a Gradle sync — then the IDE will detect the module as an Android library